# Using `std::min` as an algorithm parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, stl, overloading

So I ran into this problem: I need to replace every element of the `std::vector<int>` with the minimum of whatever came before it (inclusive).

Naturally `std::partial_sum` comes to mind - if I could pass `std::min` as the `BinaryOp`, it would do the job.

Well turns out I can't do that because `std::min<int>` is an overloaded function - it works for both `int` and `initializer_list<int>` and `partial_sum` template can't be instantiated with the unknown type.

Usually this is resolved by having a class with a templated `operator()`, like `std::plus<void>` etc, but standard library doesn't seem to have one for `min` and `max`.

I feel like I either have to implement my own `T min<T>(T,T)`, which will be an exact clone of `std::min` with the exception of not having an `initializer_list` overload, or to implement my own `class min` akin to `std::plus`. Both feel kinda wrong because one would expect standard library to have such a basic thing, and also basic things are often tricky to implement:)

So here are my questions:

1. Is there any **proper** way to solve the problem in question? i.e. without introducing new vague constructs/writing more than a couple of lines of code.
2. Is it correct to assume that this became a problem in C++11, after `initializer_list` overload of `min` was introduced? So C++11 broke the code that relied on explicitly instantiated `std::min`?

Thank you!

Comment: As a general rule, never use the address of a function, unless the API you use explicitly says you can do that. Otherwise, function APIs only tell you how you can *call* functions, and implementations are free to realize functions via multiple overloads, even with overload sets none of whose members have the publicly advertised signature.

Comment: @KerrekSB this actually looks like the answer I've been looking for (the second part anyway), thank you!

Comment: I think the Standard actually says something like that about *member* functions, but what it should really be a general principle.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Wrap it in a lambda:

```
std::partial_sum(v.begin(), v.end(), v.begin(), [](auto& a, auto& b) {
    return std::min(a, b);
});
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this version requires C++14 for the `auto`-parameters in the lambda.

Comment: this is probably my best bet, but what about the other part? is it correct that `partial_sum(v.begin(), v.end(), v.begin(), std::min<int>)` used to work before C++11?

Comment: @Ap31 Two of the big compilers (GCC and Clang) supports options to build with specific versions of the C++ standard through the `-std` option. You can use it like `-std=c++03` to tell the compiler to use the C++03 standard instead. By doing this you can easily check the second question quite easily yourself.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude good point, well it looks like [it did work](https://godbolt.org/g/BVwzJg). this is kinda dumb to be honest.

Comment: OK in light of what @KerrekSB said it appears that passing `std::min<int>` was a bad practice to begin with, so not much of a loss. I'll accept this now.

Comment: Sorry for necroposting, but is there a way to workaround when `std::min` is required to be used as a template parameter like `Compare` in [set](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/) : `template < class T,class Compare = less<T>> class set;`?

Comment: @madhur4127 Sorry for necroanswering, just noticed your post :)  

So in c++20 we're going to have stateless lambdas finally working in unevaluated contexts, which means you'll be able to use `decltype([](T a, T b){ return min(a,b); })` as a template parameter

Answer (score 22):

You can initialise a pointer-to-function variable of appropriate type and pass that, or explicitly static_cast.

```
int& (*min)(int&, int&) = std::min<int>;
std::partial_sum(v.begin(), v.end(), v.begin(), min);
```

Comment: Actually, you can even cast it on the fly, but readability suffers.

Comment: Are you sure `int& (*min)(int&, int&) = std::min<int>;` compiles? I'm getting `no matches converting function 'min' to type 'int& (*)(int&, int&)'` error with gcc 9.2.

Answer (score 1):

If the above doesn't compile, try to add const modifier:

```
const int& (*min)(const int&, const int&) = std::min<int>;
```